# Testing techniques repository?

Tags: test-management, manual-testing, test-design, learning, self-education

I was wondering if there are any repositories or wikis of formal testing techniques - test design ideas, like pairwise or boundary. I couldn't find one so far.

Thanks!
Ahmet

Comment: Probably not, but can you give a few examples of what you mean by techniques - do you mean t"formal" est design ideas like pairwise testing and boundary analysis, or general ideas like "test for foreign characters and high contrast"?

Comment: Agreed that a few examples would help - need a bit more detail for this question to be answerable.

Comment: I meant **techniques** as in formal test design ideas, like pairwise or boundary.

Comment: Ah ok. Still not sure what usage you're thinking of making of a repository though? What do you think one would be useful for? Are you thinking of having a list as a prompt for someone who already knows the techniques and when and how they're best applied? (A bit like the "Prime me" option in Session tester, which gives you one liner suggestions that *might* lead you to think of other tests you haven't tried)  I can't see that being useful unless you do already know the techniques, it takes judgement to decide what's appropriate.

Comment: Actually I was thinking about a wiki of formal testing techniques. I am not aware of all techniques available around and I guess that would be great to have a place were you can learn about them.

Comment: Maybe something like a Design Pattern archive for developers, but with testing techniques?  I could see that being useful.  It seems analogous to this site http://www.dofactory.com/Default.aspx

Comment: Yes Ethel, that would be the idea behind it. Will try to get it done. If anyone wants / can help, please ping me!

Comment: Actually, I found out that wikipedia got a nice portal about testing: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portal:Software_Testing.

Answer (score 5):

Ahmet,

I agree your thought of a wiki for testing techniques could be a valuable idea for software testers.

The best testing technique repositories that I am aware of are of the "dead tree" variety.

Lee Copeland's "A Practitioner's Guide to Software Test Design" is the best book on the topic in my view.  Available only in book format.

Also well worth checking out (particularly since he has generously made pdf versions of it available for free) is Torbjörn Ryber's "[Essential Software Test Design](http://www.onestopsoftwaretesting.com/ebook-essential-software-test-design/)." (Available in hardcover book or free pdf download).

Lastly, while not technically "testing techniques," Michael Hunter's "[You are Not Done Yet](http://www.thebraidytester.com/downloads/YouAreNotDoneYet.pdf)" has a long list of excellent quick ideas to consider testing before you declare that you're finished.

Hope these help.

Comment: Thanks Justin, interesting links.
I am wondering what would cause all these repositories to go into the "dead tree" variety :).

Answer (score 1):

The Wikipedia [Software Testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category%3aSoftware_testing) category sounds like the sort of thing you're after.

Comment: That is also what I eventualy found out.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check out the [Software Testing Club Wiki](http://wiki.softwaretestingclub.com/w/page/36395044/Heuristics) - the checklists and heuristics sections are particularly relevant, given what you've said in comments.

For resources on test design specifically, check out the [Test Design](http://www.testingeducation.org/BBST/#tab5) course materials available at [testingeducation.org](http://testingeducation.org/wordpress/). Once you've done that, check out the other [BBST materials](http://www.testingeducation.org/BBST/#tab1). There is enough there to keep you busy for a couple of years, assuming that you also have a day job!